# UTF-8 text not fetching accurately in CodeIgniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

UTF-8 problem in CodeIgniter  from mysql Problem

when i fetch utf data from mySql database using codeigniter active record then my text show like this

à¦¬à¦¾à¦‚à¦²à¦¾ à¦¨à¦¾à¦® à¦šà§‡à¦• à¦•à¦°à¦¾à¦° à¦œà¦¨à§à¦¯

actual text is

বাংলা নাম চেক করার জন্য

i have checked the config file

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Without using Codeigniter i can show the text accurately in web site.

Answer (score 0):

Is your site outputting in UTF-8? You should check the Response Headers (via Chrome or Firebug) to ensure your page's 'Content-Type' header has a `charset=utf-8` response.

This may also be set in php.ini, using the `default_charset` directive.

Comment: i checked.
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: thanks all ...  solved.. i tried all but failed . finally i found the error which is the data(utf) which i am saving the character set of the database is lalin for this that utf data actually saving a converted data of utf for this if i call the data with set this mysql_set_charset($encoding);
 then it again convert for this i can't get the actual data..

sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

You also have to set the charset of the current mysql connection:

```
mysql_set_charset($encoding);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have specified correct character set, in your html.

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

Make sure you have include the above `meta` tag in the top of your html.

In case of HTML5: use `<meta charset='utf-8'>`

Comment: Have you followed the other answer telling you to set the mysql's charset to. Use this `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` when you are entering the data on the database. and see if the error follows